# Select same column from multiple tables only WHERE something = something

Tags: sql

I have two tables with very similar structures.

```
Universidades
nombre | contenido | becas | fotos etc etc etc
Internados
nombre | todo | becas | fotos etc etc etc
```

I want to write an SQL statement that will select the `nombre` from both of them and return it as an array only when it matches. From what I have seen `UNION SELECT` seems to be the way to do this. I added `WHERE` on the end and I think this is where its going wrong. So far I am receiving the first row of the first table.

What am I typing wrong?

```
$db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$data = $db->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM internados UNION SELECT nombre FROM universidades WHERE nombre = ?");
$data->execute(array($nombre));
```

**apologies, I want to retrive one result from these two tables. Namees in the `nombre` column are all individual and different in both tables**

Comment: What does "return it as an array only when it matches" mean?

Comment: Return all information from that row in array format when nombre is equal to the value passed to it

Comment: What DBMS and version, please? Also, what does "an array format" mean? In SQL there are rows and columns. That is it!

Comment: I'm using MAMP. I'm passing the info into a variable and making it an array, $info = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: So it sounds like you want one row per `nombre`, but only if it appears in *both* tables.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One issue to point out before we solve the problem is that each query in a `UNION` is distinct and requires its own `WHERE` clause. The only clause that applies to the `UNION` as a whole is `ORDER BY`. So your query as is needs some tweaking:

```
SELECT nombre
FROM dbo.internados
WHERE nombre = ? -- the added line
UNION
SELECT nombre
FROM dbo.universidades
WHERE nombre = ?
;
```

Second, if you want the two tables to both have the same `nombre` (which is not completely clear but I'm guessing that's right), then that won't work because it simply returns one `nombre` if the value is found in *either* table. Probably the best way to solve this is to just do a join:

```
SELECT I.nombre
FROM
   dbo.internados I
   INNER JOIN dbo.universidades U
      ON I.nombre = U.nombre
WHERE
   I.nombre = ?
   AND U.nombre = ? -- perhaps not needed, but perhaps helpful
;
```

I am not 100% sure that I understand exactly what you're looking for, so please speak up if I've missed the mark.

You can think about `JOIN` and `UNION` this way:

- **`JOIN`**: connects rows *horizontally*

  - Matches them on conditions
  - Creates new *columns*
  - Doesn't exactly create rows because all data comes from existing rows, but it *will* duplicate a row from one input when the conditions match multiple rows in the other input. If both inputs have duplicates then it multiplies the count of rows from one input by the count of matching rows from the other.
  - If there is no match condition at all (think `CROSS JOIN`) then you can get a cartesian product which is each row in one input matched to each row in the other.
  - When using an `OUTER` join--`LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FULL`--if rows from the inner input (or either input with `FULL`) do not match the other, `NULL`s will be placed into the columns for the other input.
- **`UNION`**: stacks rows *vertically*

  - Generally, creates new *rows*
  - No conditions are used, there is no real matching
  - `UNION` by itself (not `UNION ALL`) will remove duplicate rows, even if one input has no rows

Note that the `UNION` could be modified to do the job, though this is not ideal:

```
SELECT nombre
FROM (
   SELECT nombre
   FROM dbo.internados
   WHERE nombre = ?
   UNION ALL
   SELECT nombre
   FROM dbo.universidades
   WHERE nombre = ?
) N
GROUP BY nombre
HAVING Count(*) = 2
;
```

In this way we ensure there are two values. Note this assumes that there can't be two of the same name in each table. If that's true, more work would be needed to make the `UNION` method do the job.

Comment: Thank you this is a great explanation of JOIN and UNION. I think I misundertood them at first and I need to restructure this.

Comment: I added a little more detail about `JOIN` and `UNION`.

Comment: and shall I add +1 for the correct version of the `union` that uses `group by` and `having`. That's how we were taught things at school (along with the teachers always saying "don't use unions or subqueries, joins FTW!")

Answer (score 6):

most of the time a `union` can be achieved by doing a join:

```
SELECT nombre 
  FROM internados 
UNION 
SELECT nombre 
  FROM universidades 
 WHERE nombre = ?
```

would better be:

```
SELECT nombre
  FROM internados i
  JOIN universidades u
    ON i.nombre = u.nombre
   AND nombre = ?
```

which is way simpler to read. (you may also use the `JOIN` syntax, but I prefer plain old manual joins).

But whether this is a `union` or a `join`, always remember that both tables get merged in the result:

```
nombre | todo | becas | fotos | ... | contenido | becas | ...
```

so basically, as you put a condition on nombre, you'll either get an empty set, or the name you've given to the query. But hthe way you've written your union, only the second set gets the `where` condition applied, not the first one. You shall put the condition on both of the queries of the union:

```
SELECT nombre 
  FROM internados 
 WHERE nombre = ?
UNION 
SELECT nombre 
  FROM universidades 
 WHERE nombre = ?
```

Comment: Old-style non-ANSI joins? In 2013!?!? What is the world coming to? I cannot recommend this.

Comment: ok, ok, fixing this, you're right it's time I get in SQL's XXIst century ;-)