# mysql - if "a"=="b" echo "discount"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm searching for a method to solve my problem.

If the e-mail I search for is in both my databases, it should echo "discount", else it should echo "no discount"

```
 //Database is connected
 $amail= "SELECT `mail` FROM `wunderte_wp793`.`Newsmail` WHERE `mail` =  (\'" . $_GET['mail'] . "\');";
        $resultamail =  $mysqli->query($amail); // query

 $email= "SELECT `email` FROM `wunderte_wp793`.`message` WHERE `email` =  (\'" . $_GET['mail'] . "\');";
        $resultemail =  $mysqli->query($email); // query

 while($resultamail == $resultemail){
        echo "Discount";
           }

        else {
        echo "NULL discount";
            }
```

Comment: `while($resultamail == $resultemail)` incorrect syntax. You want to use `if()`, or a `while`, then an `if()`. `==` compare, `=` equals.

Comment: You need to fetch data `$resultemail->fetch_row()` the use your `if() `condition

Comment: You could do this all in a single SQL query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092697/select-same-column-from-multiple-tables-only-where-something-something

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL `if`

```
SELECT if(mail=email,'Discount','NULL discount') result FROM 
`wunderte_wp793` 
WHERE `mail` =  'xyz' or email='xyz'
```

MySQL `IF` function is one of the MySQL control flow functions that returns a value based on a condition.