# selecting information from 2 tables returns error

Tags: php, mysql

I do something like this

```
<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot Connect : '.mysqli_error());
$sql = "select username from education_info,profile_info where username ='j_spaxx22'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) )
{
    echo $row['fullname'] ."". $row['email'] ."". $row['city'] ."". $row['state'] ."". $row['lga'] ."". $row['inst_name'] ."". $row['study_course'];
}
?>
```

And I get this Error

> Error: Column 'username' in field list is ambiguous

What am I getting wrong?

Edit:

When i do a Query like this

```
$sql = "select * from education_info,profile_info";
```

I get all the tables correctly

but when i do something like this

```
$sql = "select username from education_info,profile_info where username ='j_spaxx22'";
```

I get an Error, what do i seem to be getting Wrong?

Comment: Is your database containing any column with `name` of `username`?

Comment: @Ankit both tables contain column of username

Comment: take a look [Select same column from multiple tables only WHERE something = something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092697/select-same-column-from-multiple-tables-only-where-something-something).

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do? and what is the logical purpose of searching for the username in two tables?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 columns with the same name `username` in your tables `education_info,profile_info`

If you dont need to `JOIN` the table , simply select from the table you want from

```
select username 
from education_info
where username ='j_spaxx22'
```

OR

```
select username 
from profile_info
where username ='j_spaxx22'
```

If you need to `JOIN` the tables

```
SELECT profile.username 
FROM profile_info      profile
JOIN education_info    education ON profile.columntojoin=education.columntojoin
WHERE profile.username ='j_spaxx22'
```

Notice that after each table a `ALIAS` is given to each table, with that you can say from which table you want to display the data. For instance `profile.username`. When 2 tables join that have the same columname, they need to be identified with the table name alias also, otherwise you get `Column in field list is ambiguous` error.

When you use `*` and no `WHERE`, MySQL will return the full dataset since it can just display the data as it is, when using filters like `WHERE`, MySQL has to know which column exactly if they exist in multiple tables.

Comment: i am trying to use OR LIKE i dont seem to know how to use that here to create a search hence i wanted to use this select * from the both tables at once then use the OR LIKE to do the filtering

Comment: When i do something like this select * from a,b... all table information come out correctly, but when i do something like $sql = "select username from education_info,profile_info where username ='j_spaxx22'"; it fails

Comment: I know, i explained why

Comment: **select education_info.username,profile_info.username from education_info INNER JOIN profile_info ON education_info.username = profile_info.username where education_info.username = 'j_spaxx22' **

or use this inner join

Answer (score 0):

use this query and get output with no error just use tablename;

```
select education_info.username,profile_info.username from education_info,profile_info where education_info.username ='j_spaxx22' and profile_info.username = 'j_spaxx22';
```

Answer (score 0):

### you can use this query

SELECT username 
FROM education_info
WHERE username = 'j_spaxx22'
UNION
SELECT username 
FROM profile_info
WHERE username = 'j_spaxx22'
;

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: fullname in C:\xampp\htdocs\workplacecentrerecruitweb\red.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\workplacecentrerecruitweb\red.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: city in C:\xampp\htdocs\workplacecentrerecruitweb\red.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: state in C:\xampp\htdocs\workplacecentrerecruitweb\red.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: lga in C:\xampp\htdocs\workplacecentrerecruitweb\red.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: inst_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\workplacecentrerecruitweb\red.php on line 8

Comment: you are only selecting username .please mention all fields in query that you want to get .for example SELECT fullname,email,username FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        $sql="select 
        education_info.username as un, education_info.col2 as c2, 
        education_info.col3 as c3, 
        profile_info.username as un2, profile_info.col2 as c4 
        from education_info LEFT JOIN profile_info ON 
        education_info.username=profile_info.username 
        AND profile_info.username ='whatever';";
```

Answer (score -1):

you should preference the field with the full table name, for example:

if the `username` field is from `education_info` table, the sql statement should be:

`select education_info.username from education_info,profile_info where education_info.username ='j_spaxx22';`

Comment: what about sql Joins?